# Sitecore GeoIP Service is not working with personalization

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

I'm working on Sitecore 7 and I have configured the Sitecore GeoIP module (Sitecore IP Geolocation Service Client 1.2 rev. 150602.zip) on our site. 
Sitecore IP Geolocation Service is running on our site's App Center.

When I tried to use its functionality with the personalization, it seems not working.
I created the following condition for a component of a page using the presentation details --> personalize

[image]

But when I access the site from the give country, the item is still exists on the page (which need to be hidden).

I did test the GeoIp module using the TestIp.aspx page and it's tracking the ip data correctly.

Can someone please advice on this.
Thanks.

### UPDATE

This actually works. There is a ip caching mechanism with the MaxMind service.
When the ip is cached the change that we made from sitecore client is not getting activated for certain time.

Is there are any config change that we can do to change or skip this caching mechanism ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you published the page? Personalization doesn't work in edit or preview mode.

Comment: Yes I have published them and the changes are available on the web database as well.

Comment: And have you check the Analytics (SQL)database, GeoIps" table? maby there are old/wrong records see the https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498

Comment: Can you try to open a fresh browser in private mode and visit your site from Sri Lanka?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore's GeoIP/MaxMind module does not resolve GeoIP information in real time. It does this in batch background processes - for performance reasons, no doubt.

I can show you a way to change this, but I would not recommend you do this in practice on any real site as calls to the MaxMind service can take a while and will block your page load until they complete.

You need to add a processor to your httpRequest pipeline, early as possible, that forces a lookup for the client IP. It will then be cached for subsequent page loads.

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.LookupManager.GetInformationByIp(string ip)
```

Where the ip argument will be your request Host.

But as I said, I really would not recommend doing it like this, unless your site is very light weight.

My suggestion to you instead of this, will be to build something up around the GeoLite database that MaxMind provides, free of charge. You will then perform lookups in a local database (instead of a web service) - for an example of how this could be done, look here:

http://sitecoresnippets.blogspot.dk/2011/12/sitecore-geoip-country-resolving-jump.html#.Vhdui_l_NBc